# Would a graphics card increase performance of Virtual Machine?

Tags: performance, graphics-card, virtual-machine, vmware

I'm using VMWare Player to run a Windows 7 VM on a Windows 7 host.  I have Aero turned on and it works pretty well for the msot part but sometimes if I'm moving too fast or min/maxing a window I can see some screen tearing and lag.

Using an old GTX 275 but I'm wondering if a more powerful graphics card would increase the performance of a virtual machine (The GUI at least)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update in 2023:

With modern desktop environments that use "compositing" (all major ones), a graphics card is very helpful in offloading this data-intensive work from the CPU. This is especially noticeable with Windows Remote Desktop, which can now use 2D graphical acceleration where available.

The check of GPU memory access is also implemented in hardware these days (provided you pass the entire GPU through or use professional GPUs with SR-IOV). VM apps that share the host GPU in software still incur some CPU overhead, but for high-enough resolution, this will be faster than software-only rendering.

---

Original answer in 2012:

I think graphics performance in a VM is more CPU-bound than GPU-bound.

Even if the VM software implemented stuff like OpenGL and/or DirectX passthrough, the CPU still has to be used to check each and every GPU operation to prevent them from accessing RAM/VRAM outside the virtual machine. This can add a lot of burden on the CPU and the buses connecting the CPU to the GPU and reduce the performance gained from offloading certain computations entirely to the GPU as copy back is now necessary.

Also, I can't find any documentation that indicates Vmware player implements DirectX 10.1 which is required for Areo, so it is possible that your Aero effects are completely simulated in the CPU.

Comment: The GPU only needs to support DirectX 9 in order to be able to run Aero.

Answer (score 3):

This really depends on the spec of the computer in question.

I haven't tested for about 5 years, but, I noticed that putting a cheap graphics card in to a machine that was using integrated graphics made general activities much faster - I can only guess that offloading stuff from the chipset increases overall performance.

That being said, from what you are saying - as you already have a graphics card, the first thing I would do is just try updating your drivers... but, I see things like that from time to time... but, a GTX 275 should be enough, so, I am inclined to say there may be another weak link in performance - perhaps your CPU just can't cope with the virtualisation - remember that graphics in the guest are most likely being emulated/run on the CPU.